# can't get and retrive user data after login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-services

I'm a newbie with angular and I'm basicly trying to set and get user data via an angular service. First thing I do is when I log-in I connect to my node route and return the data if the user placed the correct data to login. With that data I want to set the property and pass all the object to the service. This in my loginController, every page is controlled via a global controller called mainCTRL. When I got there, I watch if the user property was set or not in the service. If yes, I take it, if not, there is no user logged.

here is the code:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $state,$location,$http,user) {

    $scope.user.nome = "";

    $scope.showRegister = function () {
        $state.go('register');
    }


    if(angular.equals(user.getProperty(), {})){
        $scope.user.nome = "";  
    }
    else {
        var userProfile = user.getProperty();
        console.log(userProfile);
        $scope.user.nome = userProfile.nome;
    }
    console.log(user.getProperty());
    $scope.user = user.getProperty(); 

    $scope.showLogin = function () {
        $state.go('login');
    }

});

app.controller('loginController', function ($scope, $http, $state,user) {
    $scope.login = function () {

        var data = {};
        data.password = $scope.loja.password;
        data.email = $scope.loja.email;
        $http.post('http://localhost:8080/login/',data) 
        .success(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            //user.setProperty(JSON.parse(data));
            $state.go('home');
        })
        .error(function (statusText) {
            console.log("failed");
        });
    }
});
```

I have the console log at a successful login. It retrives me an object, I want to pass that object to the service, and retrieve the property I want in the angular view. The problem is that I get this error every time:

```
angular.js:9509 TypeError: Cannot set property 'nome' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (controller.js:60)
    at invoke (angular.js:3762)
    at Object.instantiate (angular.js:3773)
    at angular.js:6884
    at angular.js:6270
    at forEach (angular.js:329)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:6257)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:5722)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:5725)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:5725)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are trying to set property `nome` of `user` object. You should first initialize `user` object before setting `nome` property of it.

```
$scope.user = {}; //add this at first line 
//OR
//$scope.user = { 
//   nome: ""
//};
```

Comment: that solved part of my problem thank you friend, but now when i do {{user.nome}} i always get a empty string on the view side